# ASP.NET multiple sitemaps

Tags: asp.net, sitemap, sitemappath, web.sitemap

I'm new to the ASP.NET. I need to create a new version of a website in another language (Portuguese to English).

I've created a new folder (/english/) with the translated pages and controls inside.

The "/Default.aspx" page has a link which redirects to "/english/Default.aspx"

Trouble is the link menu is still on it's original language, and the other pages in the new folder won't load. I suppose he loads the default sitemap file in the root folder instead of the one inside the new folder.

How can i make the page load the sitemap file that i have inside this new folder so it can load the new link menu?

Comment: Specify a relative link to the sitemap file, not a full path. BTW wasn't there a way to make the pages internationalized? Did you HAVE to copy the entire website?